# Displaying diamond question mark character in Korean characters using str_replace

Tags: php

I'm replacing **'*'** in the second letter of the variable named `$author` but the result seems error.

NOTE: I already placed the `<meta charset="utf-8">` but the error still the same.

Here's the example code

```
$str_to_replace = "*";
$author_second_char = $row['author'][1]; // value: �
$author_display = $row['author']; //value: 제드
$author = str_replace($author_second_char, "*" ,$author_display );
//example output = �*�드
```

Comment: Can you share the value of ($row['author'][1],  & $row['author']

Comment: Already updated Sir Indra

Comment: No its not there. Please share the contents of $row['author'][1], & $row['author']

Comment: Please check again Sir Indra, I already updated my post.

Comment: We need to know the value of `$row['author'][1]`. Your update shows `// value: �`

Comment: If you are getting this value from mysql, then did you try `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Answer (score 0):

Korean uses multibyte characters, so you cannot use the string as an array like structure, because each position will only represent part of each Korean character. Instead, you'll need to split the string into an array based on the number of bytes used to store each character. Trial and error yielded a byte length of 3 for Korean characters.

Here's a code snippet for how to implement it. I simplified it to do a straight replacement once the correct position was identified.

```
$a = '제드';
$str_to_replace = "*";

$author_array = str_split( $a, 3 ); // necessary because korean uses multibyte characters
$author_array[1] = '*';
$author = implode( '', $author_array);

echo("<br>$a<br>$author");
```

Output:

```
제드
제*
```